# Preventing power loss Arduino

Tags: arduino, capacitor

We are building a rocket flight computer with Arduino MEGA which will be powered by a 9V Duracell battery. In other forums we asked what to watch out for while building this computer and one of the answers were:

> Watch out for power failures, batteries might not work properly under high g's
>   .
>   They suggested that we use Capacitors to prevent any power failures.

- How should we connect this capacitor to the circuit?
- What kind of a capacitor should we use?

The 9V battery will be connected to Arduino MEGA via the VIN and GND pins.

Comment: wow, how much acceleration do you plan on having?

Comment: Also, if the acceleration is strong enough to negatively influence the small amount of ion movement within a battery necessary to drive an ATMega, I'd be *very* careful about whether the crystal oscillator, the electrolytic caps, the connectors… on the Arduino still work

Comment: Ion movement? I don't think so. It's more a question of the battery briefly moving away from the contacts on its holder. Less of a problem with 9V battery clips, but the battery itself needs to be firmly anchored. There are mainly three occurences of high-G, not all in the same direction: launch, ejection charge firing, and landing.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Deep ends on tech usd but can be hundreds of g in some cases.

Comment: This design is frankly *insane*.  If you are building a rocket large and powerful enough to loft an Arduino MEGA you really, really need to know what you are doing to the degree where you'd never consider flying something so excessively large and heavy.  Sanity would be making a small board with a QFN or QFP processor chip and something low mass as a power source, maybe a coin cell.  If you have to use an off the shelf "Arduino" board at least pick a "nano", if you want more resources get an ARM-based feather or teensy.

Comment: Max acceleration is 4-5g. And max speed will be around 0.8 mach. We are building 2 rockets one will go up to 1500 meters and the other will go to 3000 meters.

Comment: @Exclose I mean I'm not an expert about any of this stuff, but what I would do is ask the person who left that original comment why exactly this would happen, and what kind of acceleration we are talking about here. You need to figure out what the problem is with a battery when it is accelerated that fast as oppose to capacitors that prohibits the function of an Arduino. The person who answered that may have been referring to full on space travel, while you may have been referring to model rockets. I would do some research about batteries at high acceleration and see what the limits are.

Comment: @ChrisStratton not necessarily insane in terms of weight or size – I know university teams with rocket platforms that would carry [500g of radio electronics](https://www.ettus.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/USRP_E312_Datasheet.pdf), simply because the rocket was large enough for that to not matter too much. What's insane is the Arduino platform, for electromechanical reasons: we're on a rocket, vibrating away, and we use pin headers of unspecified mating...

Comment: What I mean is that people flying such a large and dangerous rocket should be aware enough not to use such a bulky, heavy, unreliable assembly.  It seems like the necessary steps of gaining experience with something smaller have been skipped.  It's easy to make an embedded solution that could fly on a b6-4...